# Using negative powers in a derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I  am misunderstanding how to use negative powers when taking the derivative of a function that was originally a quotient.

For example:

$$f(t)=\frac{t^2+t^3-1}{t^4}$$

$$f(t)=t^2+t^3-1+t^{-4}$$

$$f'(t)=3t^2+2t-4t^{-5}$$

$$f'(t)=\frac{3t^2+2t-4}{t^5}$$

However checking my answer I see that I am making a mistake somewhere and I am not sure where.

Comment: $$\frac{t^2+t^3-1}{t^4} = t^{-2} + t^{-1} - t^{-4}$$

Comment: $f(t) = (t^2+t^3-1)(t^{-4})$ in line 2. You have to multiply the entire numerator by the entire denominator. Then you can use exponent laws to get to @DanielFischer's answer (you can also use exponent laws right away and Daniel did, but you can do it in steps if that makes more sense to you).

Comment: How exactly did you get from line 1 to line 2? The operation is division (by $t^4$), not addition. And from line 3 to line 4, for that matter.

Comment: Just remember that, whatever exponent n could be (positive or negative), the derivative of x^n is always n x^(n-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember how fractions work when you're dealing with numbers:

For example: $\frac{6+4}{2} = \frac{6}{2}+\frac{4}{2} = 3+2 = 5$

What you're saying is $\frac{6+4}{2} = 6+4+1/2 = 10.5$ which is clearly incorrect.

As I said in the comments, $f(t)=\frac{t^2+t^3-1}{t^4} = (t^2+t^3-1)(t^{-4})$

Another way to do it is to split up the numerator into its separate parts first:

$$f(t)=\frac{t^2+t^3-1}{t^4} = \frac{t^2}{t^4} + \frac{t^3}{t^4} - \frac{1}{t^4}$$

Then exponent laws say that if you are *dividing* with a common base, you *subtract* the *exponents*. So you get:

$$\begin{align*}f(t)&= \frac{t^2}{t^4} + \frac{t^3}{t^4} - \frac{1}{t^4} = t^{2-4} + t^{3-4} - t^{-4}\\  &= t^{-2}+t^{-1}-t^{-4} \\ \end{align*}$$

Then differentiate with power rule (which you did correctly, you just took the derivative of the wrong function originally).